# Trapping rain water algorithm complexity

Tags: c#, algorithm, complexity-theory

Trying to solve [Trapping Rain Water](https://leetcode.com/problems/trapping-rain-water/) problem, and can't understand why my solutions is not passing complexity check:

```
    public int Trap(int[] height) {
        int res = 0;
        int chk = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < height.Length; i++){
            chk = Math.Min(height[..i].Max(),height[i..].Max())-height[i];
            if(chk > 0){
                res += chk;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

```
Compile:    0.024s
Execute:    0.85s
Memory: 3.90Mb
CPU:    0.874s
```

But this one (recommended) is passing:

```
    public int Trap(int[] land) {
       var wall = 0;
        var water = new int[land.Length];
        for(var i = 0; i < water.Length; i++) {
            wall = Math.Max(wall, land[i]);
            water[i] = wall - land[i];
        }
        wall = 0;
        var sum = 0;
        for(var i = water.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            wall = Math.Max(wall, land[i]);
            water[i] = Math.Min(water[i], wall - land[i]);
            sum += water[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

```
Compile:    0.024s
Execute:    0.03s
Memory: 0b
CPU:    0.054s
```

Why such a huge difference? Is it because of array `slice[..i]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array Slicing operations are of **O(N)** time complexity. 
So, the total time complexity of your code becomes **O(N<sup>2</sup>)**. 
That's the reason for the **TLE**.

While the recommended code is solving that problem within O(N) time complexity only.